# Presta Module not visible/installed

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I installed an auction module http://addons.prestashop.com/en/marketplace-prestashop-modules/7197-auction-product.html.

Then I uninstalled it, made some changes, and tried to reinstall. It was not shown in modules listung, although Presta said the module was installed. The files where present at /modules/auction, but in ps_modules table I can't find it.

Then I tried to reinstall the original version - without any changes - with the same result. The module seems to be uploaded, but is not installed. How to solve this?

Using Presta Shop version 1.5

Answer (score 0):

What about if u open your ftp public_html/modules/ and manual delete it? After this upload correct version and try to install/uninstal/reset. Sometimes it helps for me.